# Rutas secundarias (routers anidados) en Express

Tags: nodejs, express

Primero, un poco de *antecedentes* y *contexto*:

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con `nodejs` + `express`.

Soy nuevo en esta tecnología, y la aplicación será de cierta complejidad. Así que la estoy realizando por *módulos*, cada uno en una ruta concreta.

**EDITO**

Tras un poco mas de *trasteo*, estoy `100%` de que el fallo está en como uso las rutas; edito, para acortarla un poco y concretarla mas.

Para una solicitud AJAX a esta URL

> `POST http://localhost:8080/auth/allowed`

Tengo el siguiente código (es un extracto, el real es mayor. Solo lo que creo relevante):

```
// main.js

const AuthModule = require( './auth' );

app.post( '/auth/*', AuthModule );

// Archivos estáticos. Sin autorización.
app.get( '*', EX.static( join( __dirname, 'static' ), {
  dotfiles: 'ignore',
  index: 'false',
  redirect: false
} ) );

app.listen( 8080 );
```

En donde **todos** los módulos cargan correctamente.

> AuthModule

Situado en el subdirectorio `auth`, con 2 archivos:

```
// index.js

'use strict';

const EX = require( 'express' );

const AllowedModule = require( './allowed' );

const Router = EX.Router( );

Router.use( function( req, res, next ) { require( 'console' ).log( 'Módulo AUTH' ); next( ); } );

Router.post( '/allowed', AllowedModule );

module.exports = Router;
```

y

```
// allowed.js

'use strict';

function Allowed( req, res ) {
  res.json( {
    lastupdate: currTime,
    users: [
      [ 'Usuario número 1', 1 ],
      [ 'Usuario número 2', 2 ],
    ]
  } );

  res.end( );
}

module.exports = Allowed;
```

Ahora, lo que pasa: cuando hago una solicitud del archivo `/login.html`, este realiza un AJAX `POST /auth/allowed`.

He establecido puntos de volcado a consola, en los que se muestra que entro al archivo `auth/index.js`. Desde ese archivo, se debería de llamar al *middleware* `auth/allowed.js`. Sin embargo, en el navegador obtengo un bonito código `404`.

Entiendo que, por algún motivo, desde el archivo `auth/index.js` **no se llama** a mi *middleware* `auth/allowed.js`; en su lugar, se continua con la tabla de rutas primaria (la que establezco en el `main.js`). Se trata la llamada como una solicitud de un archivo estático, que `static` intenta responder.

Lo que yo esperaría es que desde `auth/index.js` se llamara a `allowed`, pero **eso no sucede**.

En el `main.js`, establezco la ruta correcta como POST.

Dentro de `auth/index.js`, utilizo igualmente un POST.

La ruta que espero seguir es

- POST `/auth` -> `auth/index.js`
- POST `/auth/allowed` -> `auth/allowed.js`.

Bueno, creo que ya está todo.

1. ¿ Donde está mi error ?
2. ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Comment: A ver si entiendo. ¿Cuando haces `POST /auth/allowed` se ejecuta el middleware pero devuelve 404?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Se ejecuta el middlewre PostModule; desde ahí, se **debería** ejecutar el Allowed, **pero** obtengo un 404. Sin error de ningún tipo por consola. Es como si PostModule ignorara al Allowed, y la ruta siguiera hacia la última, que lo busca como un archivo estático (app.static).

Comment: @GustavoGarcía La idea es main.js -> auth.js -> allowed.js. Siento que sea tan larga la pregunta; creo que el fallo está en `authModule`, pero no estoy seguro, así que he puesto todo lo que creo relevante :-/

Comment: Haz un simple `console.log` en diversos puntos de `Allowed` para ver si entra al módulo correctamente. Además, **no olvide siempre llamar a** `next()`  **en todo middleware**.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Pregunta editada. La he acotado todo lo que he podido.

Comment: Ahora estoy desde el portátil que desde el móvil no veo claro xD. El problema está en que estableces de forma errónea los estáticos. Lo correcto es usarlo como *middleware*: `app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')));`.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía No sirve, hace lo mismo :-( Creo que no uso bien las rutas en 2 niveles. El primer nivel, el principal, si funciona. Pero el segundo, no. El que establezco en el archivo `auth/index.js`

Comment: Tendrás que olvidarte de las rutas anidadas. Ten un solo router para cada endpoint. Es decir: `Router.post('/auth', AuthModule).post('/auth/allowed', AllowedModule);`.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía ¡¡ Lo encontré !! Maldita sea la documentación de `express`, que explica todos los casos **menos** el que yo necesito !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡¡ Por fin !!

Después de *tropecientas* pruebas, al final he *atinado* con la respuesta.

El asunto es:

#### 1. En el *router* **principal**, las rutas a montar mediante *router*s adicionales **no pueden tener barra al final** ni *comodines*:

`/ruta/` -> Incorrecto.
`/ruta/*` -> Incorrecto.
`/ruta` -> ¡¡ Correcto !!

#### 2. En el *router* principal, las rutas a montar mediante *router*s adicionales **se han de montar mediante `use( )`**

`get( 'ruta', MIDDLEWARE )` -> Incorrecto.
`use( 'ruta', MIDDLEWARE )` -> ¡¡ Correcto !!

#### 3. El *router* secundario, se usa de forma normal.

Admite cualquier método: `get( )`, `post( )`, ...

Añadir al final del *router* secundario un `use( function( req, res, next ) { next( ); } );`. **No** estoy seguro de la obligatoriedad de esto, pero en mi caso concreto, con una ruta final (en el *router* **principal**) para gestionar los archivos estáticos, funciona correctamente.

**Cualquier incumplimiento de lo anterior** NO genera ningún error ni aviso ni nada de nada. Sencillamente, nuestra ruta *anidada* **es ignorada**. Nos puede costar **un buen rato** descubrir lo que está pasando :-(

PD.-

Muchas gracias a @GustavoGarcia por su interés y consejos ;-)